Time integration of first-order ODE with higher-order information
Suppose I wish to derive a numerical integrator for the first-order ODE $$x'(t)=F(x(t)).$$  By differentiating both sides of the expression in $t$, I can write a second-order relation also satisfied by $x(t)$: $$x''(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\left(x'(t)\right)=\frac{d}{dt}F(x(t))=DF(x(t))\cdot x'(t)=DF(x(t))\cdot F(x(t)),$$ by the chain rule, where $DF$ denotes the Jacobian of $F$.
Using Taylor series, I could write
$$x(t+h)=x(t)+F(x(t))\cdot h + \frac12 DF(x(t))\cdot F(x(t))\cdot h^2 + O(h^3).$$
If we omit the $O(h^3)$ term, we get quadratic-error explicit time integrator for our ODE.
Does this time integration strategy where we know derivatives of $F(\cdot)$ have a name?  What are its drawbacks?

I'm not sure if I understand 100%, but as per my comment below, I use a numerical technique that I call the "Taylor Series Method" (it is also used for manual calculations as you show), although with a name like that it is very hard to search for!  Also the old autodiff.org site seems to be defunct (listing software like FADBAD, C-XSC, Tides)!  If you want to search, the method seems to be originally by a guy called Ramon E. Moore.

Addendum:  The method is also related to something called the Differential Transform https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262733462_Introduction_of_the_differential_transform_method_to_solve_differential_equations_at_undergraduate_level, but is numerical throughout.

If you apply this to a PDE problem, then you get Lax-Wendroff Method. There are also what are called two-derivative Runge-Kutta methods which use not only $F(x)$ but its derivative also. Earliest paper is likely: Chan, R.P.K., Tsai, A.Y.J.: On explicit two-derivative Runge–Kutta methods. Numer. Algorithms 53,
171–194 (2010). There is quite an explosion of work on these kind of methods, especially for conservation laws, flow problems.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2432062/how-solve-this-nonlinear-trigonometric-differential-equation/2499684#2499684 for an example with a simple but non-trivial ODE for the series computation. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3663073/115115 has an example for the second order Taylor method (which is not really different from any, likewise second order, RK method).

Thanks, all! @cfdlab, do you have any pointers to places where these strategies have been linked to energy conservation? This would be extremely helpful for a project I am currently working on. Thanks!

I have seen works on conservation laws where total energy conservation is automatic since finite volume methods are used, e.g., https://doi.org/10.1186/s42774-019-0004-9

Not too surprisingly, it is referred to as a
"Taylor series method." The drawback is that, in general, it
may not be easy to compute the derivatives of $F$, particularly as you add more terms to the Taylor series to improve the accuracy.
But the method can be quite attractive if $F$ has a specific form, say
a polynomial in $t$.
Other approaches to implementation of the method include using
automatic differentiation methods or symbolic calculus systems to calculate the higher-order derivatives.

Thanks!  This is indeed the Google search term I was missing ;-) .  I can't find many documents that take this method seriously --- it seems to be among the zoo of relatively unused numerical integrators.  I can't tell if it's just because of the cost of computing DF, or if the integrator itself isn't useful. Maybe now that automatic differentiation is more common (e.g. using libraries like Pytorch) we should revisit...

In many real applications, $F$ is very complicated. Computing its derivatives is not always easy. Worse, $F$ is in many cases no differentiable -- say if a part of the device you're modeling switches on or off at specific times or based on conditions on $x$.

This makes sense!  I work on a lot of graphics problems where $F$ is likely to be fairly clean/differentiable --- maybe I'll play with these!

One other potential pitfall is that, although using derivative information can lead to a higher order scheme, the error coefficient may grow quite large and the higher-order scheme may require smaller step sizes than the lower order scheme to hit some desired error tolerance.

I must interject here that the statement "it may not be easy to compute the derivatives of F"  applies only to explicit ("by hand") calculations.  If you are doing this numerically (as I do in my ODE project) then there are simple (but apparently not very well known) recurrence relations that can be used to calculate derivatives arbitrarily (up to degrees of hundreds and more!) for compositions of many common (and uncommon) functions.

@m4r35n357: This is often known as "propagation of truncated Taylor series" or "Taylor series arithmetic". It is apparently a more obscure part of the AD topic.

@LutzLehmann well I have never heard that term used ;)  To me, Taylor Series Arithmetic covers the recurrence relations (e.g. the mul() function in the code), whereas the non-trivial "evolution step" using Horner's method to evolve the state (the identity U[k+1] = V[k] / (k + 1) -- see code) is something else on top of that.

I have learnt to put also the use of the first order ODE to evaluate the series for sine, cosine, exp etc. with the cost of about one series multiplication under that umbrella name.

@LutzLehmann Sure.  I have a fairly complete set (sqr, divide, trig, hyp functions, log & power, sqrt etc.).  The example in my answer is the smallest self-contained solution I could come up with.  If you would like to continue this perhaps the comments under my answer would be a more appropriate place . . .

To follow up from my comments, for which I can't easily find many references (the paper that I first saw on the subject was this one).
If you have a Linux box, a Mac, or a VM of either, you can try a Lorenz system simulation using the arbitrary-precision calculator GNU bc.
define void output (x, y, z, t) { print x, " ", y, " ", z, " ", t, " _ _ _ 0.0\n" }

define horner (n, j[], h) {
    auto i, s
    for (i = n; i > -1; i--) s = s * h + j[i]
    return s
}

define mul (u[], v[], k) {
    auto j, p
    for (j = 0; j < k + 1; j++) p += u[j] * v[k - j]
    return p
}

scale=15; n=12; h=0.01; steps=10000; x=-15.8; y=-18.48; z=35.64; sigma=10; rho=28; beta=8.0/3.0

output(x, y, z, 0.0)
for (step = 1; step < steps + 1; step++) {
    x[0] = x; y[0] = y; z[0] = z
    for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        x[k + 1] = sigma * (y[k] - x[k]) / (k + 1)
        y[k + 1] = (rho * x[k] - mul(x[], z[], k) - y[k]) / (k + 1)
        z[k + 1] = (mul(x[], y[], k) - beta * z[k]) / (k + 1)
    }
    x = horner(n, x[], h); y = horner(n, y[], h); z = horner(n, z[], h)
    output(x, y, z, h * step)
}
quit

Copy this to a file called lorenz.bc, then run:
BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 /usr/bin/bc lorenz.bc

The parameter "n" is the order of the Taylor series, experiment with it!
Note that all derivatives are calculated, not approximated - step size (h) is not used at all in the derivative calculations (the "k" loop), only the final "integration" step (like an Euler step, but using Horner's method).
The "scale" parameter determines precision (in decimal places), and like "n" can be set to arbitrary values.
One of the biggest problems I had when first coding my GitHub project was the rare and haphazard documentation of the method. Ultimately, I made my own "explanation" based on different approaches from various sources, but hammered into a consistent and clear presentation (although I am not a mathematician!). See this file for a pretty complete description of how it all fits together. The master branch is no longer in development; there are now two current branches: pure_c (including GNU bc for arbitrary precision work) and python.
The c version is the one to use in earnest (with the much slower bc versions for arbitrary precision and high-order work).  The Python version is mostly for learning/debugging, and use in an interactive Python shell.  Both codebases have intensive test suites.
